# Mi aplicación no muestra "Mensaje no encontrado"

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función "search" que busca textos dentro de un array.
Ahora mismo funciona perfectamente cuando encuentra los objetos, pero de no hacerlo, no consigo que me muestre el texto "Mensaje no encontrado".
Los resultados se muestran en un alert en ambos casos.

Os paso el código:

```
function search() {
  let results = '';
  let value = document.getElementById("input_busqueda").value;
  let listaMensajes = channels[currentChannel].messages;
  for (let messageItem of listaMensajes) {
    if (messageItem.mensaje.includes(value)) {
      //results.push(messageItem);
      results += '-' + messageItem.usuario + ': ' + messageItem.mensaje + ', ' + messageItem.fecha + '\n'
    }else{messageItem.mensaje.includes("Mensaje no encontrado")}
  }


  alert(results);

  console.log('resultados', results);
}
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría así:

```
function search() {
  let results = '';
  let value = document.getElementById("input_busqueda").value;
  let listaMensajes = channels[currentChannel].messages;
  for (let messageItem of listaMensajes) {
    if (messageItem.mensaje.includes(value)) {
      //results.push(messageItem);
      results += '-' + messageItem.usuario + ': ' + messageItem.mensaje + ', ' + messageItem.fecha + '\n'
    }
  }
  if(results == "") {
    results = 'Mensaje no encontrado'
  }
  alert(results);
  console.log('resultados', results);
}
```

de este modo compruebas al final, ya fuera del bucle, si la variable **results** ha sufrido cambios o no. Y si no los ha sufrido dentro del bucle es que no ha encontrado nada y por lo tanto le asignamos el `Mensaje no encontrado` para que lo muestre en el *alert* final.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Así es mucho más sencillo!! Funcionó!!!